# java7: Files.walkFileTree() and "System Volume information" on windows systems

Tags: java, windows, nio, ntfs

Feeding Files.walkFileTree() with a root folder (e.g. "T:/") produces the error:

```
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: T:\System Volume Information
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:372)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2706)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
```

The callback preVisitDirectory() is not called:

```
            @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( Path aFile,
                                                  BasicFileAttributes aAttrs )
            throws IOException
        {
            if ( "System Volume Information".equals( ( aFile.getFileName() ) ) )
            {
                return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
            }

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
```

Neither the apache FileUtils.deleteDirectory( new File( "T:/" ) ) can handle this situation.

I came across to write following code:

```
    public static void deleteDirRecursive( Path aDir ) throws IOException
{
    if ( aDir == null )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "aDir must not be null" );
    }

    if ( Files.notExists( aDir ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    if ( aDir.isAbsolute() && aDir.getRoot().equals( aDir ) )
    {
        myLog.debug( "Given path object is a root. On windows we cannot delete 'System Volume Information' folder!" );

        // -> iterate over the entries in root and skip "System Volume information"
        Arrays.asList( aDir.toFile().listFiles( 
            new FilenameFilter() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean accept( File aDirectory, String aName )
                {
                    return !"System Volume Information".equals( aName );
                }
            } )
        ).forEach
            ( dir -> 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if ( dir.isDirectory() )
                        {
                            deleteDirRecursive( Paths.get( dir.getAbsolutePath() ) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Files.delete( Paths.get( dir.getAbsolutePath() ) );

                        }
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e )
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "", e );
                    }
                }
            );

        return;
    }

    if ( !Files.isDirectory( aDir ) )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "given aDir is not a directory" );
    }


    Files.walkFileTree( aDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
    {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile( Path file,
                                          BasicFileAttributes attrs )
            throws IOException
        {
            Files.delete( file );
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory( Path dir, IOException exc )
            throws IOException
        {
            Files.delete( dir );
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

    } );
}
```

Notice that the biggest part of this code is only the special handling of "System Volume Information" (the whole "if ( aDir.isAbsolute() ...."). Very ugly.

Is there a more elegant solution to exclude this folder from a tree walk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's late, but I had this issue too; I'll document it there.

[`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) has a method called `FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(T file, IOException exc)`

`SimpleFileVisitor` implements it by re-throwing the exception.

Just override that method in your own implementation, handling the exception the way you deem necessary.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the very same solution, but forgot to update my question; thanks for pointing this out so that the correct answer can be found here.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the answer to the question is simply to be aware the class has more things to override, once I realized that, it's another case of hard to find but easy to fix. Your question came up #1 result when I searched for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with one of my packages called [java7-fs-more](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more):

```
final Path path = Paths.get("T:");

MoreFiles.deleteRecursive(path, RecursionMode.KEEP_GOING);
```

This will keep on deleting files and directories even if it fails at one point.

On return, you will get (in your case) a [`RecursiveDeletionException`](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/exceptions/RecursiveDeletionException.html); all exceptions raised during the deletion are "attached" to this exception (see `Throwable#getSuppressed()`).

Another solution (not guaranteed) would be to check the `dos:system` attribute of the path; if true then you may want to avoid deleting it.

Note that in a `FileVisitor` you unfortunately only have access to the `BasicFileAttributes` when you visit a file; what you want to do in order to check `dos:system` is for example to do this:

```
Files.readAttributes(path, DosFileAttributes.class).isSystem()
```

Yet another solution, since you seem to be using Java 8, is to use `Files.walk()` and filter the entries; unfortunately reading the attributes will raise an IOException so, here again, I use another package of mine, [throwing-lambdas](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas), to somehow work around it:

```
final ThrowingPredicate<Path> notSystem
    = path -> !Files.readAttributes(path, DosFileAttributes.class).isSystem();

final ThrowingConsumer<Path> remove = Files::delete;

try (
    final Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("T:"));
) {
    stream.filter(notSystem.orReturnTrue()).forEach(remove.orDoNothing());
}
```